# Can mirror displays, but can no longer join them

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, multiple-monitors, display

Laptop running 22.04 with a second external display.

For months, I've been running these joined (extended). Then I encountered the Mesa upgrades issue, which meant Chromium didn't display properly. I recovered from this and all was working as before - but only for a day. When I started the laptop the next day, the second display was backlit, but black, except for my pointer, which moved around as normal. Literally nothing else displayed on the external display, but if I mirror the displays, everything works as normal. I believe I've accepted some other updates, but am not sure what they are.

Thanks for any ideas.

Installed NVIDIA packages as of 1 Aug 2023:
[image: Installed NVIDIA packages as of 1 Aug 2023]

Comment: Some additional information. I'm running an AMD Ryzan 5 5600H CPU with an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 GPU. I dual boot to Windows, where the displays work in joined mode with no issues. 

I also tried booting from an Ubuntu USB with a 22.04.2 ISO installed. Joined displays also worked here, but I had a different graphics issue where the screens were mainly bright yellow with nearly unreadable text. When I installed Ubuntu on this machine about 8 months ago, the ISO then was 22.04.01 which displayed normally.

Comment: Booting to other ISO versions of 22.04 doesn't help, but I've discovered that the problem doesn't exist 23.10. I only upgrade when there's a new LTS, so looking forward to 24.04, as there seems to be no fix for 22.04.